# Autofac Resolve by name only?

Tags: autofac, caliburn.micro

Does Autofac support service resolving via name only? Or must I always specify a service type?

I want to do:

```
container.ResolveNamed("Plugin"); // or container.TryResolvedNamed("Plugin", out instance);
```

not

```
container.ResolvedNamed<ISomeInterface>("Plugin"); // etc
```

where "Plugin" would be a registration name/key, not a type.

Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make sense, unless you want it to return `object`.

Comment: Actually, that works fine, because I'm in a Xaml binding environment anyways. Actually it's a small integration piece with Caliburn in question, if that helps provides any larger context. Caliburn's Bind class has a method that tries to resolves from the chosen IoC container by name only, not type.

Comment: Specifically: Bind.ModelChanged(...) is the method in question. It attempts to retrieve via IoC container using the line:

target = IoC.GetInstance(null, containerKey);

So, Caliburn is assuming the supplied IoC flavor will support retrieving in this way. Not sure if Autofac is going to be able to work in this way. (IoC is just a facade class in the Caliburn source proper that abstracts away the particulars of any container...)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify a `Type` to resolve a service in Autofac, either via generic parameter or a `Type` parameter. Two options:

1. Register all your relevant services with and additional `.Named<object>("service name")`.
2. Maintain your own `Dictionary<string, Type>` so that you can look up the type yourself before resolving via Autofac.

I'd probably go with option 1, assuming you have control over all the registration code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem:

```
    private Type GetTypeForName(string key)
    {
        return (
            from reg in Container.ComponentRegistry.Registrations 
            from service in reg.Target.Services.OfType<KeyedService>()
            .Where(service => service.ServiceKey.ToString() == key) 
            select service.ServiceType).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Obviously, not a perfect solution, since it is conceivable there could be multiple registrations with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain uniqueness of keys among services, this extension method will help:

```
    private static object ResolveSingleOrDefaultByName(this IComponentContext cc, string name)
    {
        var reg = cc.ComponentRegistry.Registrations.SingleOrDefault(r =>
            r.Services.OfType<KeyedService>().Any(s => name.Equals(s.ServiceKey)));
        return reg == null ? null : cc.ResolveComponent(reg, Enumerable.Empty<Parameter>());
    }
```

It will return null, if key was not found.